# Unable to delete a file on different user's directory

Tags: files, permissions, readonly

I've two user's **abc** & **xyz** and the user abc has been added to the group  xyz via `usermod -a -G xyz abc` and here the file permission on home directory of xyz i.e `/home/xyz`:

`drwxrwxr-x  2 xyz xyz  4096 Mar 23 16:13 xyz`

Now inside home directory of xyz, there is a file **testfile**, now when I'm trying to delete the file testfile from user abc, I'm unable to delete the file and getting **Permission Denied**.

What am I missing? I've read various answers for this but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1) You need to look at the owner/group permissions of the directory containing the file or directory you try to delete as that entry will be modified if a file (or directory) within it is deleted.

2) The account (group membership) of user xyz is modified but the user is not using a new shell and therefore the new group membership is not active yet. Try `id -a` within the context (shell) of the user which is trying to delete the file to get the current groups

Comment: Thank you @Lambert for the quick response. I've already verified these two possibilities before asking question. Those are okay. I got a hit from a answer of the question https://superuser.com/questions/784952/linux-group-member-cannot-delete-file-with-rw-permission/784954#784954 but not get the success. Can you help with that?

Comment: Can you also provide the `ls -l` output from the file you are trying to delete? In the question I can only see the directory.

Comment: Sure, it is `-rwxrwxr-- 1 xyz xyz 5 Mar 23 16:13 testfile`

Comment: Actually, that worked after log out and re-login